# help regarding rounding off numbers

Tags: java

float per = (num / (float)totbrwdbksint) * 100;

i m getting the value of per as say 29.475342   . i want it to round off upto two decimal places only.like 29.48 .how to achieve this?

Comment: ya i meant 29.48 sorry for mistype

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should do this as part of the formatting - the floating point number itself doesn't have any concept of "two decimal places".

For example, you can use a [`DecimalFormat`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) with a pattern of "#0.00":

```
import java.text.*;

public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        float y = 12.34567f;
        NumberFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#0.00");
        System.out.println(formatter.format(y));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As [Jon implies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033122/help-regarding-rounding-off-numbers/2033126#2033126), format for display. The most succinct way to do this is probably using the `String` class.

```
float f = 70.9999999f;
String toTwoDecPlaces = String.format("%.2f", f);
```

This will result in the string `"71.00"`

Comment: Probably should also add the conversion from string to float since it seems like from his example he wants the number to remain as a float.

Comment: @Anton - there is no guarantee that parsing the result back to a float will result in the desired level of precision. The code `System.out.format("%.15f", 29.475342f);` prints a result `29.475341796875000`. Even if this worked, allocating a char array as an intermediary would be the wrong way to perform the operation.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to control how rounding is done you should check BigDecimal ist has several rounding modes. http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html

Answer (score 1):

You need to be careful here, this answer is not related to java, it relates to all aspects of decimals in many programming languages hence it is generic. The danger lies with rounding numbers, is this, and it has happened in my experience and know that it can be tricky to deal with:

- Supposing you are dealing with prices on items, the pricing you get from a retail supplier may be different to the price the computer tells you, sure it is marginally small, but it could add up to big money.
- Adding a sales tax on a price can either be positive or negative, it can impact the operating margin of the profit/loss balance sheets...

If you are in this kind of arena of development, then my advice is not to adjust by rounding up/down...it may not show up on small sales of the items, but it could show up elsewhere...an accountant would spot it...Best thing to do is to simply, truncate it,
e.g. 29.475342 -> 29.47 and leave it at that, why?, the .005 can add up to big profit/loss.

In conjunction to what is discussed here...electronic tills and registers use their own variety of handling this scenario, instead of dealing with XX.XXXXXXXXXX (like computers, which has 27/28 decimal places), it deals with XX.XX.

Its something to keep in mind...

Hope this helps,
Best regards,
Tom.

Comment: As you say, the 0.005 could add up to a big profit/loss, which is precisely why you *do* round rather than just truncating - so that half the time you get profit, and half the time you lose. Bankers' rounding is designed to make this even fairer, I believe. Truncation means the bias is *always* in one direction - if I'm paying you and I always truncate the amount I have to pay, you're bound to lose out.

Comment: @Jon: What would be the best banker's rounding algorithm to use in C# as I am curious to know how it works... Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use the formatted print method System.out.printf to do the formatted printing if that's what you need